# Use amd modules with typescript 1.6 targeting es6

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to use typescript 1.6 with amd modules while targeting es6?

This worked in 1.4 and was useful as no browser currently have es6 module support but do have a lot of ES6 features built in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use AMD while targeting ES6, in case of ES6 has it's own module system. So while you are targeting ES6 - it uses SYSTEM modules by default. Use ES5 and choose any of `[amd, common, system, umd]`.

`--target 'ES6'`
or
`--target 'ES5' --module 'amd'`

It was unable to use AMD+ES6 since TS1.5

Use SystemJS to work with ES6 modules

Comment: SystemJS seems like the right path forward to get ES6 modules working now. Thanks

Comment: Version 1.7 (to be released soon) will add support for --module when target is ES6 https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4806

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you can use the [compiler options](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler-Options) `--target` to use `'ES6'` and the `--module` option to use `'amd'`.

However, targeting ES6 is an experimental feature:

> [1] These options are experimental.

Maybe the TypeScript team has not yet added support for this.

If `--target` and `--module` don't solve your issue you are going to need to report this issue at the [TypeScript issues page](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues).