# What is the correct type of the service parameter in the constructor and from where it should come

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have two angular 1 services in two different files, and I am using the first service in the second service. How can I type the first service in the constructor to make typescript and myself happy without importing the first service?

Using internal modules it would make it easy, but in that case I cannot load the files correctly. Moreover I cannot mix internal and external modules.

// app.module.ts

```
import angular from 'angular';

import FirstService from './first.service';
import SecondService from './second.service';

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.service('firstService', FirstService);
app.service('secondService', SecondService);

export app;
```

// first.service.ts

```
class FirstService {
    constructor() {}
}

export default FirstService;
```

// second.service.ts

```
class SecondService {
    constructor(firstService: ??) { }
}

export default SecondService;
```

UPDATE

I can make ts happy with importing the module in the second service:

```
import FirstService from './first.service';

class SecondService {
    constructor(firstService: FirstService) { }
}

export default SecondService;
```

But is it correct? I feel that I am making the DI somehow broken with importing the module as extra in the second service just for the type safety...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the export syntax of your `first.service.ts` and `second.service.ts` modules:

// first.service.ts

```
class FirstService {
    constructor() {}
}

export { FirstService };
```

// second.service.ts

```
import { FirstService } from './first.service';

class SecondService {
    constructor(firstService: FirstService) { }
}

export { SecondService };
```

## Update

You also need to update the import statement:

```
import { angular } from 'angular';

import { FirstService } from './first.service';
import { SecondService } from './second.service';

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.service('firstService', FirstService);
app.service('secondService', SecondService);

export { app };
```

Comment: But if I add to the constructor like this : firstService: FirstService, than tsc doesnt recognise it, even with this exports (getting error: Cannot find name 'FirstService'.).

Comment: Have you also update the import statement (see updated answer)?

Comment: yes, I tried. Strange, because if I put a namespace for the FirstService (eg.: namespace Services { class FirstService {}}), than it is finding it (like, Services.FirstService). But in this case the issue that I cannot import it as external module.

Comment: Mixing internal and external modules is not going to work try to use the same syntax for all your import and export statements. I have updated the answer once more. Also for using ES6 module syntax you are going to need the latest version of TypeScript , take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32703081/use-amd-modules-with-typescript-1-6-targeting-es6/32705396#32705396

Comment: Yes I know, and I don't want to mix them. I updated the question, please see it. thanks a lot

Comment: What you did is correct when working with external modules you need to import each of the dependencies of that file in the top of that file. I will update my answer.